# For cycle only loops once and crashes

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, crash

I'm trying to do a macro where VBA looks for a specific word in a column and when it finds the words, it copies the entire row from one workbook to another. It can find the word more then once, so I'm trying to make it loop though it only loops ONCE in the for cycle and then stops.

Here is the for.

```
Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Documents and Settings\1848052\Mis documentos\Portafolios\Vistas\Portafolio.xlsm")
i = 9

For j = 8 To 1000
    celda = Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("B" & j).Value

    If celda = area Then
        Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("B" & j).Select
        fila = ActiveCell.Row

        Windows("Portafolio.xlsm").Activate         ' Copiar row
        Range("A" & fila & ":" & "V" & fila).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("Vista RPAs.xlsm").Activate        'Pegar row
        Range("B" & i & ":W" & i).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

As I mentioned before, it only loops once and then this:

```
Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("B" & j).Select
```

is the part that crashes and I get "Error 1004". How do you think I could fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, avoid using `select` statement! The most likely issue is that you're trying to select range on the nonactive workbook. Try to add `Windows("Portafolio.xlsm").Activate` before the line `Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("B" & j).Select`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the trick! How would you suggest I could find the row number of the cell without using the select statement?

Comment: try this: `fila = Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("B" & j).Row` or just simply `fila = j` because `Range("B" & j)` is in row № j :)

Comment: I've rewrote your code in the most appropriate way to avoid `Select` and `For` statements. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code instead. It avoids using `For j=8 to 1000` statement (it uses `Find` method instead - it's much better when you have many rows).

```
Sub test()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Workbooks.Open ("C:\Documents and Settings\1848052\Mis documentos\Portafolios\Vistas\Portafolio.xlsm")
   i = 9

   With Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo")
       Set c = .Range("B8:B1000").Find(area, LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then
           firstAddress = c.Address
           Do
               Workbooks("Vista RPAs.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i & ":W" & i).Value = _
                .Range("A" & c.Row & ":" & "V" & c.Row).Value
               i = i + 1
               Set c = .Range("B8:B1000").FindNext(c)
           Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
       End If
   End With
   Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Close
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that it's better to change `Workbooks("Vista RPAs.xlsm").ActiveSheet` to `Workbooks("Vista RPAs.xlsm").Sheets("SomeSheetName")`

Comment: One last question, can I do this procedure without having to open the "Portafolio.xlsm" file? Or is it completely necessary to open it?

Comment: You should open it. I think if you search, you can find a method to not open it, but it will be complicated. You can just call `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the very beggining of your functoin and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of function, and user will not notice that you have opened a book. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Simoco got it first time, selecting in a non-active workbook.
 (just the if block)

```
    Workbooks("Portafolio.xlsm").Sheets("FemCo").Range("A" & fila & ":" & "V" & fila).Copy

    Workbooks("Vista RPAs.xlsm").activesheet.Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

btw, tidied up with some valid points, but the 'better' way to do this would be to run a loop around a find statement, which searches the relevant range for hte word you want, and exits when the first found record is found again, or no records are found,  There are plenty of examples of this.

Comment: Try to add `Sheets("FemCo")` after `Windows("Portafolio.xlsm")` and `ActiveSheet` after `Windows("Vista RPAs.xlsm")` in second and third line (I guess, without `ActiveSheet` it wouldn't work) and change `fila` to `j` because they are the same